# What's the Problem with ruby, jekyll, and rack/handler

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundler

I'am forked github project [sujaykundo777](https://github.com/sujaykundu777/devlopr-jekyll/tree/master) and wishing to customizing my blog

for that, I downloaded Ruby to make blog with 127.0.0.1
but It's too many error to making blog

To resolve the error, I deleted and reinstalled Ruby and its dependent items, and followed the instructions from other communities, but all was of no use.

It's the error

1. jekyll: version unknown..

```
PS C:\Users\ProBook\Desktop\upked.github.io> ruby -v
ruby 3.2.3 (2024-01-18 revision 52bb2ac0a6) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
PS C:\Users\ProBook\Desktop\upked.github.io> jekyll -v
jekyll: version unknown
PS C:\Users\ProBook\Desktop\upked.github.io> gem uninstall jekyll

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
        jekyll-4.3.3
```

2. 'require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler (LoadError)

```
PS C:\Users\ProBook\Desktop\upked.github.io> bundle exec jekyll serve --trace
Configuration file: C:/Users/ProBook/Desktop/upked.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/ProBook/Desktop/upked.github.io
       Destination: C:/Users/ProBook/Desktop/upked.github.io/build
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 39.734 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/Users/ProBook/Desktop/upked.github.io'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-admin-0.11.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler (LoadError)
```

3. bundler: command not found: serve

```
PS C:\Users\ProBook\Desktop\upked.github.io> bundle exec serve --livereload
bundler: command not found: serve
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

How can I fix these errors? What should I do??

Uninstall and Installing ruby, bundler, etc..

```
gem uninstall --all
```

searching with Github, stack overflow, jekyll QnA. But I couldn't find anything matching my error.

Comment: Did you follow the Windows instructions from the sujaykundo777 repo? You are required to run: `bundle update`, `bundle install`, `bundle exec jekyll -v`. It says so here: https://github.com/sujaykundu777/devlopr-jekyll/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#for-windows-

Answer (score 0):

I encountered one [similar issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-admin/issues/705) and I think it's related to rack 2 -> 3 incompatibility.

Try to add `gem "rackup"` in your `Gemfile` and try `bundle` again.

Also it'd be helpful to share your `Gemfile` to help debugging.